# Writing value in two input fields simultaneously ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, input

I face an problem when I enter the value in one input field it appears in another input field as well.

On a screenshot I start typing in bottom field but the numbers start appearing in top field as well.

It also happens if I enter value only in top input field it appears in bottom as well. Like it's always doubling the value which I put in any field.

[image]

**CODE**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

const symbols = [
  "ADABTC",
  "AIONBTC",
  "ALGOBTC",
  "ARDRBTC",
  "KAVABTC",
  "ETHBTC",
  "ETCBTC"
];

function PriceTriggerField() {
    
 const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
 const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState([]);
 const handleChange = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const results = symbols.filter(symbols =>
      symbols.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );
    setSearchResults(results);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      <Form>
          <input id='hey'
        type="text"
        placeholder="Symbol"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      </Form>
      
       <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Price"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
<ul>
    {
        searchTerm.length > 0 && searchResults.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)
    }
</ul>
      <Button variant="secondary">Set</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PriceTriggerField;
```

**EDIT1**

After taking @Ziarno answer I start receiving this error.

Example - I enter `ADABTC` in first field and when I start entering numbers in another field it breaks with this error (Watch below)

When I enter values in both input fields my react app breaks and I'm receiving this error

```
TypeError: searchSymbols.map is not a function
PriceTriggerField
src/Components/PriceTriggerField.jsx:46
  43 |         value={searchSymbols}
  44 |         onChange={handleChangeSymbol}
  45 |       />
> 46 | <ul>
  47 |     {
  48 |         searchTerm.length > 0 && searchSymbols.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)
  49 |     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to have 2 different state values for 2 different inputs

```js
...
 const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
 const [searchSymbol, setSearchSymbol] = React.useState("");
 const handleChangeTerm = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };
 const handleChangeSymbol = event => {
    setSearchSymbol(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      <Form>
          <input id='hey'
        type="text"
        placeholder="Symbol"
        value={searchSymbol}
        onChange={handleChangeSymbol}
      />
      </Form>
      
       <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Price"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChangeTerm}
      />
...
```

Secondly, you don't have to use setState for symbols, just show them filtered by search term. Remove the whole `React.useEffect` and do this:

```js
<ul>
    {symbols
       .filter(symbol => symbol.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm))
       .map(item => <li>{item}</li>)
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: I was confirming that it's working before but now I'm facing the problem that when I enter values in both input fields my react app is getting broken and I receive this error - TypeError: searchSymbols.map is not a function

Comment: I edited main question with a full error and explanation. Please take a look